# Parsing a PKCS7 detached signature hash

Tags: hash, openssl, digital-signature, smime

I'm trying to manually verify signatures of Apple iOS Passbook files, which are PKCS #7 detached signatures of the RSA key of the Apple developer who created the file.

Which means there's a file "signature" which is the detached signature of a "manifest.json" file. I'm using the novelty "Titanic boarding pass" pkpass file from http://www.flonsolutions.com/fantastic_voyages.html for testing. Doing:

```
openssl smime -verify -in signature -content manifest.json -inform der -noverify
```

comes back with success, so I know the signature should be valid. Now, parsing apart the `signature` file, I can have decoded the DER-encoded ASN.1 data and shows that the attribute being signed is a SHA1 digest of the message, resulting in `733538fde88843c7ad24fb71674dbdd372df7b4d1`. Running `openssl sha1 manifest.json` shows that indeed the SHA1 of that file is indeed `7335...b4d1`.

Now, parsing out the `SignerInfo` bits of `signature`, I can grab the OctetString that's the RSA encryption of their signature:

```
BC C5 F9 F2 53 FD 2C 13 EA CE 64 BB 89 85 60 82 78 63 5B 04 FA F8 BF 7E 2A 6C 20 
5D C3 C8 E8 8A 2F E3 4D B9 8E 1C A1 42 DF 2B 46 89 76 63 0B 8A DD E5 8A 69 4E D0
CF 3F E7 36 1E F8 7F 49 0D 27 EC 0F 73 76 5D 62 A1 4E 8A 43 AB EC ED 2E CD E7 69
3F AD 32 48 0A 79 52 DB 36 5B 61 94 71 3F B3 09 1E 80 17 94 31 06 AF E6 A3 A5 A0
D6 B7 71 31 ED 4C 6F C1 5C B6 4B 79 E5 7A BA BC 1D AD BB D2 F7 39 05 16 73 2C AE
74 E3 9C 4F 7E A7 B1 90 38 FC 92 78 9F 70 C0 D0 94 83 83 EC 01 F4 B6 16 36 4B EE
BC BA DD AC 23 64 4B C2 93 21 9E 9B 21 64 9E 7C 1B 72 87 0B C1 7D 9C 6A 9B AA AB
36 67 F8 7C 7B 8D 9E 88 FC 95 C8 29 57 8B EB B9 5C F6 AB 59 64 CA 87 ED DE 50 BA
67 C0 26 F8 5B FD 47 10 B0 A6 4E D8 D6 F0 E9 A0 DE 2B 6B D4 84 2A 91 A6 A7 27 22
CE D6 5F D2 C7 87 56 A4 E6 E4 D6 D3 C9
```

Using the certificate's Public Key from earlier in the `signature` file:

```
-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----
MIIBIjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOCAQ8AMIIBCgKCAQEAzEjQiB/QgOWX2QF6CGtCiq1ZDyRzJJKJ
4ZW6cuF2MdtOi4If+IhTHcVkdeJ+/cacuRFcscNOXODjriCbAbmTVYTFx290n4vQ1qvPuu3/T41f
4dZHvAM9dmUHuN7M/f/SyGWJiFSYj3VY7S+jyH5zvskGp84YNkHB/Uky3ZFZElOwoOltRNVL25Rw
52nIMVrqO+Cyn2T2LSkk/6yjSll46TyjYuTDEev4XvYhIQBfbraP9rUabRkf1k0EuXl7qM2GeKGM
vq9sQwMRPVFFM2Fa/8xUeA4D/4AWR4S4shuVUxWOx8bq57RNRDogTr4rotaAOyDACu0aS37fWJmQ
zExr3QIDAQAB
-----END PUBLIC KEY-----
```

I can successfully decode the RSA encryption and get a result. The result of the decryption is another ASN.1 DER-encoded string, which is:

```
30 21 30 09 06 05 2B 0E 03 02 1A 05 00 04 14 5B AC 45 51 B9 A5 51 68 28 89
51 59 1F 62 31 9B A7 15 50 CB
```

Parsing that out, it's indicating that `5bac4551b9a55168288951591f62319ba71550cb` is the SHA1 hash of something. **But that's not the SHA1 of `manifest.json`** (`5bac...50cb` != 
`7335...b4d1`).

So, what am I supposed to be comparing that decrypted SHA1 to? I know that the owner of that certificate encrypted this particular DER-encoded string, but I don't see how they match. What part of the RSA/PKCS7 process am I missing here?

Comment: I think this question is better suited for stackoverflow.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The digest calculation is described in [CMS](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5652) (the new name for PKCS#7), section 5.4. Namely, when there are signed attributes, then what is signed is an encoding of the set of attributes; since one of the attributes contains the hash of the data file on which the signature object applies, this signature extends to the data file. See this paragraph:

> A separate encoding
> of the signedAttrs field is performed for message digest calculation.
> The IMPLICIT [0] tag in the signedAttrs is not used for the DER
> encoding, rather an EXPLICIT SET OF tag is used.  That is, the DER
> encoding of the EXPLICIT SET OF tag, rather than of the IMPLICIT [0]
> tag, MUST be included in the message digest calculation along with
> the length and content octets of the SignedAttributes value.

so the hash should be computed over the complete encoding of the `SignedAttributes` value, except that you replace the first byte (which should be 0xA0) with the byte which encodes a universal tag `SET OF` (that's 0x31, if I remember correctly).

Comment: Thanks; that did it! Those signature files sign off on the date of the signature as well, so there was other attributes to sign.